# \n is not working in plist?

Tags: iphone

I created array.plist file where I am storing key value pair
e.g
key = MY_FIRST_MESSAGE
Value = Welcome\n I am happy to serve you.

in xml format



Welcome\n I am happy to serve you.

I received this sting in dictionary and display in textview like below code
textView.text = [myDict objectForKey:MY_FIRST_MESSAGE];

But
I am not able to get newline. It should be look like below

Welcome
I am happy to serve you

But I got it like
Welcome\n I am happy to serve you

On textview view,
I debug this problem, my got string from plist is like Welcome\n I am happy to serve you.
Please suggest me how to remove \n from string which are from plist?
I tried \n, /n, /\n all combination.

Thanks
Manu

Answer (score 3):

.plist files are XML, so you should be able to use an actual newline character rather than the string "\n".

Failing that:

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```